# ImageMagick 7.0.7-34 installation gives "undefined reference to `PNGSetExifProfile'"

Tags: imagemagick

I'm trying to install ImageMagick 7.0.7-34 on a ubuntu 16.04,
I'm using wget to download the latest version (7.0.7-34) from here `http://www.imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick.tar.gz`, then after extracting the tar, I'm running the following inside the extracted folder:

```
sudo ./configure --with-pango
sudo make
```

which gives the following error:

```
make  all-am
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/local/sources/ImageMagick-7.0.7-34'
  CCLD     utilities/magick
MagickCore/.libs/libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.so: undefined reference to `PNGSetExifProfile'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:7042: recipe for target 'utilities/magick' failed
make[1]: *** [utilities/magick] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/sources/ImageMagick-7.0.7-34'
Makefile:5178: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I've searched but found nothing concerning this error!, anyone knows how to fix this?

**--Update--**

A similar [issue](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues/1136) was opened on ImageMagick's github repo, just an hour ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a mistake we made when adding support for the PNG eXIf chunk. This will be resolved in ImageMagick 7.0.7-35. If you upgrade your libpng library you can also fix the build. You will need a version of libpng that has `PNG_READ_eXIf_SUPPORTED` defined.

p.s. Next time it will be better to create an issue here: https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues. You will get a much faster response.

Comment: @AbdelHady next time pls post here as well...stackoverflow is the number one source for developers...

Comment: @SkalárWag stachoverflow was the 1st place came to my mind when all searches failed :)

Comment: @dlemstra, it wasn't clear to me for a moment where is your repo, so I started with the question here, then continued searching but found that another one already made the issue on your repo, so I just connected the issue with the question here, but generally I got your point

Comment: @dlemstra, would you please tell us when the 7.0.7-35 will be released for public download?

Comment: @AbdelHady We will try to publish a new release later today.